# RESTful API  и практика

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, rest

Друзья, в процессе освоения нового для меня способа разработки ядра для сайта возник ряд вопросов. Буду благодарен, если поделитесь опытом.

Прочитал несколько статей на тему RESTful API, [например эту](http://habrahabr.ru/company/SECL_GROUP/blog/204510/). К сожалению, примеров особых не стретил, везде описывается общая концепция. Например, запрос

> api/users/

выдаёт (в статьях предполагается, что ответ приходит в формате json) список пользователей, то, как этот список вывести на страницу? Логично, что ранее должна быть загружена структура (шаблон), в которой есть *некое* место под этот список, тогда (опуская вопрос загрузки шаблона) как *узнать* (т.е. получить ID элемента) это место, чтобы вставить туда список?

Если речь идёт о единичных случаях, вопрос не стоит, можно вручную парсить, что-то изобретать на лету. Но когда интерфейс сложный, сущностей десятки, то неизбежно встаёт вопрос автоматизации.

Или, скажем, текущий шаблон вообще не рассчитан на подгружаемые данные. То есть, загружая список пользователей, нужно ещё и шаблон под него где-то взять. И как-то распихать список по шаблону...

Подскажите, братцы, как принято решать подобные задачи. 
Спасибо.

Comment: REST API - это концепция *отдачи* данных. Ее не очень заботит то, кто и как будет эти данные использовать, ее волнует наличие параметров и авторизации. Однако же, обычно REST API идет как источник данных для SPA, которое просто грузится из корня и подгружает шаблоны, стили и прочее как обычную статику (хотя шаблоны при желании тоже можно REST'ом раздавать).

Comment: Знакомясь с материалами, обнаружил точку зрения, что рест на сегодня исчерпал  потенциал как раз по причине того, что это именно концепция отдачи данных. То есть можно сделать что угодно, некоторые будут ругать за отход от "политики партии", а некоторые говорить, что за подобным подходом будущее (как понял, это hypermedia http://habrahabr.ru/post/144259/, у меня  слабое понимание этого термина)

Выходит, как опция — ждём сообщения тех, кто поступает именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@hcuser](/users/25423/hcuser), вероятно, вам стоит познакомиться со способами реализации MVC ([Model-View-Controller](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller)) на клиенте. Модель - это данные, получаемые через RESTful API, представление - некий HTML-шаблон, контроллер - javascript, обрабатывающий действия пользователя. 
К счастью, "все уже украдено до нас" и существует достаточно модных библиотек/фреймворков реализующих это дело. Некоторые яркие представители:

- [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)
- [Angular](http://angular.ru/)
- [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)
- [Ember](http://emberjs.com/)

Они предлагают несколько разные подходы, про все из них немало информации на том же Хабре.

Чтобы прочувствовать и сравнить "вкус" этих библиотек - зайдите на http://todomvc.com/ и посмотрите исходники разных реализаций простого приложения - списка дел.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я уже заглядывал в бекбон и ангуляр, смысли примерно понятен, но в данном случае цель другая — понять и научиться делать самому. А потому, может, кто поделится опытом самостоятельного пути через тернии к звёздам.

Comment: Самому - это хорошо, но не очень практично. Можете тогда [взять какой-нибудь шаблонизатор](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/), а данные таскать ручками: